# how to refresh an html page from server side (c#) in windows

Tags: c#

I have the following scenario:
 1.- A PC based on Linux that has a big display connected by HDMI to show real-time traffic information to drivers on the road.
 2.- An HTML page with the traffic information that runs over chromium on that PC.

I need to implement a web server (in C#) that runs over windows that refresh the html page in order to update the traffic information showed in the display.
I've searching information about Reactive Extensions (Rx) for .NET and SuperWebSocket but I don't really know if they will be suitable for my needs and moreover which one would be the best solution.
Can anybody help me, please?
Any help would be very appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the high level architecture of your application. By using a server side frame work to control the state of your client application and creating a dependency between them.

Dependency's make it harder to maintain a good architecture and a clean code base.

One approach would be to have an API end point which has the data you want to display and a client application that refreshes every few minutes that reads the end point and displays that information. By giving your client application the responsibility of refreshing the content from an API endpoint, you have removed the dependency between them.

This architecture will also allow you to scale both the client application and the API end point independently.

The templates that come with .NET core in visual studio are a good place to start.